# Why is this regex acting greedy, when I've told it not to be?

Tags: python, regex

I've attempted to encode the following [EBNF grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) for my system's macros into a regular expression (below), but despite my best efforts it appears to *greedily* match across multiple macros: it doesn't stop at the closing `}}@`.

```
    Expand ``@{{...}}@`` references which may appear in Step parameters.
    The syntax is described by the following EBNF grammar::

        depdata = "@{{", source identifier, ":", attribute, "}}@"
                | "@{{TAGS:", expression, "}}@" ;
        source identifier = ? printable 7-bit ASCII ? ;
        attribute = "DATADIR" | "TAGSFILE" | "RESULT_INT" ;
        expression = ? printable 7-bit ASCII ? ;
```

and the Python regular expression I've come up with

```
@{{(?:(?:(?P<id>.*?):(?P<attr>DATADIR|TAGSFILE|RESULT_INT))|TAGS:(?P<expr>.+?))}}@
```

**Edit**: Added missing `+` within `expr` group

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9v0jj1pTyN_k8V0t)

When finding all the matches in the following test-case, I expect the result to be *three* matches, but I only get two:

```
@{{TAGS:sTagsJob << "job||ID||source"}}@ test  @{{job:DATADIR}}@ email body @{{job:DATADIR}}@ blah
```

The matches I expect are:

1. `@{{TAGS:sTagsJob << "job||ID||source"}}@` with the `expr` group set
2. `@{{job:DATADIR}}@` with `id` and `attr` groups set
3. `@{{job:DATADIR}}@` (again) with `id` and `attr` groups set

But instead, the matches are:

1. `@{{TAGS:sTagsJob << "job||ID||source"}}@ test  @{{job:DATADIR}}@`
2. `@{{job:DATADIR}}@`

How come the non-greedy matches (`.+?`) seem to be acting greedy? What have I missed?

(And yes, I'm aware the EBNF grammar is silly and could be improved by always having the fixed strings appear on the right hand side. But that's not my question: I want to learn why my regex-fu has failed me)

Comment: The `.*?`, although "lazy", will still try to match as many as it can to return a valid match. Try [`@{{(?:TAGS|[ -~]+?):(?:DATADIR|TAGSFILE|RESULT_INT|[ -~]+?)}}@`](https://regex101.com/r/mJ9lX3/1)

Comment: If you need to keep the groups: [`@{{(?P<id>TAGS|[ -~]+?):(?:(?P<attr>DATADIR|TAGSFILE|RESULT_INT)|(?P<expr>[ -~]+?))}}@`](https://regex101.com/r/mJ9lX3/3).

Comment: I had to lookup `[ -~]` on an ASCII table to work out it was 7-bit printable ASCII. Nice!

Comment: See [*My favorite regex of all time*](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/my-favorite-regex/) :)

Comment: If `.*?` is lazy, how come it tries to match as many as it can? Isn't that greedy behaviour? How do `.*?` and `.*` differ?

Comment: The dot matches any character (but a newline, if the DOTALL mode is off). The `*` and `*?` match 0+ characters, just the `.*` grabs everything at once, and `*?` does it step by step, checking the subsequent subpatterns for a match before retrying the `*?`. You confuse the meaning of "greedy" here. **Avoid using dot matching patterns if you do not really mean that, if the pattern is known**. Here, the printable ASCII pattern is required - then use it, do not rely on dot matching.

Comment: I wish your last comment was an answer, that *that* is the key understanding I was missing, and is really the knowledge I was looking for!

Comment: I have posted my answer, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot matches any character (but a newline, if the *DOTALL* mode is off). The `*` and `*?` match 0+ characters, just the `.*` grabs everything at once, and `*?` does it step by step, checking the subsequent subpatterns for a match before retrying the `*?` subppatern. You confuse the meaning of "greedy" here: note that regex tries to find a match "by all means", it retries quantified subpatterns when a mismatch occurs at some location in the string, the engine backtracks with greedy quantifiers, it does *everything* to fetch a match. Lazy quantifiers are not a guarantee that your pattern won't overfire just because of an extra `?` in the quantifier definition.

Thus, **avoid using dot matching patterns if you do not really mean that, if the pattern is known**. Here, the printable ASCII pattern is required - then use it, do not rely on dot matching.

```
@{{(?P<id>TAGS|[ -~]+?):(?:(?P<attr>DATADIR|TAGSFILE|RESULT_INT)|(?P<expr>[ -~]+?))}}@
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ9lX3/3)

Note that `[ -~]` matches any printable ASCII character.  See [*My favorite regex of all time*](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/my-favorite-regex/).

The pattern matches:

- `@{{` - leading delimiter
- `(?P<id>TAGS|[ -~]+?)` - an `id` group matching `TAGS` or 1+ printable ASCII chars, but as few as possible since it also matches `:` (you can restrict the character class with a lookahead to exclude `:` or replace with `[ -9;-~]` to make the pattern even more optimal and get rid of `?` with this quantifier)
- `:` - literal `:`
- `(?:(?P<attr>DATADIR|TAGSFILE|RESULT_INT)|(?P<expr>[ -~]+?))` - matches  `DATADIR`, `TAGSFILE`, or `RESULT_INT` and places into `attr` group, or matches one or more printable ASCII (as few as possible) and places into group "expr". Again, it is lazy here because `[ -~]` matches a `}`. Otherwise, you could use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) here: `(?:(?!}}@)[ -~])+`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ9lX3/4)
- `}}@` - trailing delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that seems to do what you want:

```
@{{(?:(?:(?P<id>[^:]*?):(?P<attr>DATADIR|TAGSFILE|RESULT_INT))|TAGS:(?P<expr>.*?))}}@
```

[This correctly matches:](https://regex101.com/r/oI3aE2/1)

```
MATCH 1
expr    [8-37]  `sTagsJob << "job||ID||source"`

MATCH 2
id  [50-53] `job`
attr    [54-61] `DATADIR`

MATCH 3
id  [79-82] `job`
attr    [83-90] `DATADIR`
```

There is one bug in your regex that prevents it from matching the `TAG` part (forgot a kleene star in `P<expr>.?))}}@`?), but that alone doesn't solve the issue with matching too much, so I changed the dot after `<id>` to be a "non-colon".

Comment: `.*?` matches any characters other than a newline, but acc. to the grammar description it should match *printable 7-bit ASCII*. Same goes for `[^:]*?` (it just matches any char but `:`).